# Finding the largest row and column, solution is inconsistent

Tags: java, sorting

Where is the logic error?.. Sometimes the solution is correct and sometimes it is not. The program is suppose to calculate the row with the greatest sum and column with the greatest sum. For example:

1 1 1 1

0 0 1 0

0 0 1 0

0 0 1 0

Then the output would be:
largest row = 0
largest column = 2 //since count starts at 0

This is what I have:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class LargestRowAndColumn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random f = new Random();

        int[][] m = new int[4][4];

        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0;j < m[0].length; j++) {
                m[i][j] = f.nextInt(2);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0;j < m[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(m[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("The largest row is index: " + computeRow(m));
        System.out.println("The largest column is index: " + computeColumn(m));
    }

    public static int computeRow(int[][] m) {

        int[] count = new int[m.length];

        int sum;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                sum = sum + m[i][j];
            }
            count[i] = sum;
        }

        int maxIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < i + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = count.length - 1; j >= i; j--) {
                if (count[i] < count[j]) {
                    maxIndex = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return maxIndex;
    }

    public static int computeColumn(int[][] m) {

        int[] count = new int[m.length];

        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                sum = sum + m[j][i];
            }
            count[i] = sum;
        }

        int maxIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < i + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = count.length - 1; j >= i; j--) {
                if (count[i] < count[j]) {
                    maxIndex = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return maxIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't print the correct row and column (the ones with greatest sum)

Answer (score 1):

Your maxIndex nested loop is too complex. It should be a single loop, checking the current max value seen so far with the current item in the loop. Something like this:

```
    int maxIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < count.length; i++) {
        if (count[i] > count[maxIndex]) {
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct , but

```
  for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0;j < m[0].length; j++) {
            m[i][j] = f.nextInt(2);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0;j < m[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(m[i][j] + " ");
        }
```

Because of the two loops:

You are creating two random 2-dimensional array instead of one. 
There is one which is being printed and the other one which is not being printed but being used for index values you require so do :

```
    System.out.print("Index" + "\t0"+"\t1"+"\t2"+"\t3" +"\n");
    System.out.print("--------------------------------------------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(i+ "|\t");
        for (int j = 0;j < m[0].length; j++) {
            m[i][j] = f.nextInt(101);
             System.out.print(m[i][j] + " \t");
        }
         System.out.println();
    }
```

This will also print the index, which may assist you

Answer (score 0):

Why you made your job difficult. Make 2 loops, 1 for calculating the row with biggest sum, 1 for calculating the line with the bigger sum.

You don't need an int array `count[i]`. In your example you calculate the row with the greatest sum, you don't need to know the sum of every row after the for loop finished, so you can use a simple `int bigRow`.

```
int bigRow = 1, sumRow = 0;

// We assume that 1st row is the biggest
// Calculate the sumRow

for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
   sumRow = sumRow + m[i][j] ;

// At this moment our maximum is row 1 with its sum. 
// Now we compare it with the rest of the rows
// If another row is bigger, we set him as the biggest row

for ( int i=1;i<n;i++) // We start with row 2 as we calculated the 1st row
   { int auxRow = 0;
     for (int j=0;j<m;j++)
       { auxRow = auxRow + m[i][j] ; }
     if (auxRow > sumRow ) { auxRow=sumRow ; bigRow = i;}
   }
```

Do the same with lines.

```
int bigLine = 1, sumLine = 0 ;
```

Let me know if you have another problem.